# Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type <char> and <char>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

While executing below code, getting this error:

> Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(char)' and 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(char)'

```
public ActionResult HolidayIndex()
{
    IEnumerable<HOLIDAY_MASTER> hdms = null;
    hdms = db.HOLIDAY_MASTER.ToList().Where(h => h.HOLIDAY_NAME.Except("Sunday") && h.HOLIDAY_NAME.Except("Saturday") && h.HOLIDAY_DEL.Equals(0) && h.REGION_ID.Equals(RegionID)).OrderBy(h => h.DOH);
    return PartialView("HolidayIndex", hdms);           
}
```

Error shows under `h.HOLIDAY_NAME.Except("Sunday") && h.HOLIDAY_NAME.Except("Saturday")`.

Actually, what I want is need to fetch all the Holyday_Names which is not equal to Saturday and Sunday.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Just as the error states, you can't use a logical `&&` on those types.  What would that even *mean*?  Semantically what are you trying to *do* in that `.Where()` predicate?

Comment: `Except` will return an eumeration, not a bolean? Do you want to know if  `h.HOLIDAY_NAME.Except("Sunday")` contains any element?

Comment: I assume you want `.Where h => h.HOLIDAY_NAME != "Sunday" && h.HOLIDAY_NAME != "Saturday")`?

Answer (score 2):

this is because linq `Exept` returns IEnumerable, you can not apply && operator to `IEnumerable`

Try this way:

```
 public ActionResult HolidayIndex()
{
    IEnumerable<HOLIDAY_MASTER> hdms = null;
    hdms = db.HOLIDAY_MASTER.ToList()
        .Where(h => 
            !(h.HOLIDAY_NAME == "Sunday" || h.HOLIDAY_NAME == "Saturday" )
            && h.HOLIDAY_DEL.Equals(0)
            && h.REGION_ID.Equals(RegionID)
        )
    .OrderBy(h => h.DOH);
    return PartialView("HolidayIndex", hdms);           
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using Linq's extension method `Except`. It removes all entries in the second collection from the first.

Its signature is defined like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Except<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second)
```

---

`String` implements `IEnumerable<char>`.

So, `h.HOLIDAY_NAME.Except("Sunday")` removes the characters 'S', 'u', 'n', 'd', 'a', 'y' from `h.HOLIDAY_NAME` and return the new `IEnumerable<char>`. 
This results in an **application of && to two `IEnumerable<char>`**, which is **not defined**, hence the error message.

---

I'm guessing you want to check that `HOLIDAY_NAME` is not "Sunday". You should do this with a simple `HOLIDAY_NAME != "Sunday"`.

Your whole method would then look like this:

```
public ActionResult HolidayIndex()
{
    IEnumerable<HOLIDAY_MASTER> hdms = null;
    hdms = db.HOLIDAY_MASTER.ToList().Where(h => h.HOLIDAY_NAME != "Sunday" && h.HOLIDAY_NAME != "Saturday" && h.HOLIDAY_DEL.Equals(0) && h.REGION_ID.Equals(RegionID)).OrderBy(h => h.DOH);
    return PartialView("HolidayIndex", hdms);           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`IEnumerable.Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb300779%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) returns a new enumeration, not a boolean, thus you cannot apply any `&&`-operator on it. However you can select those elements from your list whose attribute `HOLIDAY_NAME` is not equal to both `"Saturday"` and `"Sunday"`. 
Use this:

```
IEnumerable<HOLIDAY_MASTER> hdms = db.HOLIDAY_MASTER.ToList()
.Where(h => h.HOLIDAY_NAME != "Sunday" &&
    h.HOLIDAY_NAME != "Saturday" && 
    h.HOLIDAY_DEL.Equals(0) && 
    h.REGION_ID.Equals(RegionID))
.OrderBy(h => h.DOH);
```

Comment: Maybe you could explain what's wrong with the OP's code ?